Cast a dart int as long(Java)
In my flutter/dart app i am using channel.invokeMethod() to run code on the Android side. When i pass a dart int via this method i get a Java Int or Long, depending on the value that i sent.
Eg.:

if i pass 100 i get an Int
if i pass 4284572001 i get an Long

If i pass the smaller number(100) i get this error message
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

If i pass the larger number it works, with the same code.
Flutter/Dart code
final int someNumber = 100;  //or 4284572001
final Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {"key1": someNumber};

await channel.invokeMethod(
            channelMethodName,
            myMap,
          );

Android side
override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
   val someNumber = call.argument<Long>("key1")
}

How to send a fix datatype(Long) from the Dart side?

Well, in Dart all integers are 64-bit (signed), so when you send an int from Dart to Kotlin using method channel, it will be treated as a Long in Kotlin
Here's how you can fix it:
final int someNumber = 100;  // or 4284572001
await channel.invokeMethod(
  channelMethodName,
  {"key1": someNumber}, // Note the colon ':' instead of comma ',' and added key ':'
);

By specifying "key1": someNumber, you're correctly passing the integer value with a key "key1".
On the Android side, you can handle it like this:
override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
   val someNumber = call.argument<Long>("key1")
   // If someNumber is null, you can handle it accordingly.
   if (someNumber != null) {
       // Process the Long value here
   }
}


Was a typo. In my code i use a colon (not comma). I edited my question. The code doesn't work with the colon either. Sometimes i get an error (when an int is passed).
